# fixture density of 0 is not working?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

i have a fixture which i set his density to 0 , but he is falling down as he HAS a weight .

```
b2PolygonShape spriteShape; //b2polygon-for box shape
    spriteShape.SetAsBox(fruit2.contentSize.width/PTM_RATIO/10,fruit2.contentSize.height/PTM_RATIO/10); //for b2polygon
    b2FixtureDef spriteShapeDef;
    spriteShapeDef.shape = &spriteShape;
    spriteShapeDef.density = 0.0;
```

the world g is -9.8 as usual.

How i set this fixture to fall down slowly ? why density of 0/1/2 doesnt do that ?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you want it to react? Do you want it to kind of float down like a feather? A feather floats down slowly because it has the force of the air pushing it back up. So in other words, apply a small enough force upwards on the object that it falls slowly, but doesn't go up. A very low density object will still fall fast without an opposing force to slow it down.

Comment: but when i do that, it some how seems that the sprites are little bit  blurry. is it has to something with the fram rate of the game ?

Comment: It's hard to say. It could be the frame rate or the way your physics step is calculated. It could also be the way the opposing force is applied.